# Use HTML as primary source for an e-book usable in Apple's iBooks?

Tags: ipad, books, html

Is this possible?  Basically, someone I am working with has a bunch of HTML documents.  He would like to put them into an e-book usable in Apple's iBooks.  Is that possible?  If so, a general pointer to the appropriate documentation would be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) on many occasions to convert HTML files to ePub and mobi format ebooks. It's the ePub format you need to use for iBooks.